# DuplicateUsername error in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.CreateAsync

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.9.

I am trying to create a new user with something like

`var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser)`

but I get a DuplicateUsername error, even though there is no record in the database that matches username or email of the new user.

Edit to add: this is only happening with a specific username/email address. The registration process works for everyone else.

Looking at the source for CreateAsync, I assume the error is being thrown by

`ValidateUserAsync` but I can't step into that code to see what validations are failing.

Is there a way to step into that code? (Setting breakpoints doesn't work)

Or is there another way to see why those validations are failing?

Edit to add registration code:

```
var newUser = new AppUser
{
  Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
  FirstName = employee.FirstName,
  LastName = employee.LastName,
  Email = employee.EmailAddress,
  NormalizedEmail = employee.EmailAddress.ToUpper(),
  TwoFactorEnabled = false,
  UserName = employee.EmailAddress,
  NormalizedUserName = employee.EmailAddress.ToUpper(),
  PasswordHash = "NOT_HELD_LOCALLY" // Passwords stored in Firebase
  CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow
};
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser);
```

Comment: You can check whether the database of the project is correct or try to use other username. If there is still an error, you can  provide the code for the relevant registration method.

Comment: The database is correct - other users are able to register. I will edit the question to add the relevant registration code.

Comment: I tested your code and found that the DuplicateUsername error occurs when the same username exists in the database. Before executing the insert statement, you can check whether there is a user with the same user name and set a breakpoint to view it. Perform the insert operation again when the same username does not exist.

Comment: But there isn't a user with the same username in the database. Earlier in the code I call _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(employee.EmailAddress) and it is null for this particular email address, but then _userManager.CreateAsync throws the DuplicateUsername error.

Comment: You can check if the username is case-sensitive and if there are no extra spaces in the username. Can you share what the particular email address and username you mentioned look like? Do you configure related custom validation in your project? And what are the related configurations of Identity in your Program.cs, can you share the related code? You can also try clearing the cache.